# Returning the exponent value of a floating point number

Tags: c, floating-point, exponent

How can I return only the exponent part of a floating point number? It's single precision so I need to get the value of the eight exponent bits.

```
int floatExp(float f) { 
 //Return the exponent value for f. return tmax if f is nan or infinity
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `frexp`?  (`frexpf` for float)

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to extract the binary exponent is to use the *frexp()* function from `math.h`.  See http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/ansic-library.html#float

If you need the decimal exponent, use the *log10()* function in `math.h`.

Comment: Or use as a cheap and only nearly accurate replacement of log10 the value of (frexp(x,&m)*3)/10

Answer (score 1):

Code certainly should pass a `float` rather than `unsigned`.

```
// int floatExp(unsigned f)
int floatExp(float f)
```

Use `isfinite` and `frexpf()`.

```
#include <math.h>
int floatExp2(float value) {
  int exp;
  if (isfinite(value)) {
    frexpf(&exp);
    return exp;
  }
  return tmax;
}
```

For base 10, a bit more work.

```
#include <math.h>
int floatExp10_(float value) {
  if (isfinite(value)) {
    if (value == 0.0) return 0;
    float exp = log10f(fabsf(value));

    // use floorf() rather than `(int) exp`.  
    // This does the proper rounding when `exp` is + or -
    return (int) floorf(exp);
  }
  return tmax;
}
```

C does *not* define that floating point nor `float` have "eight exponent bits".  It also does not define that the exponent is a binary one.  Many implementations use [IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point format: binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) which does have an 8-bit power-of-2 biased exponent.

A hack way is to use a union.  This non-portable method is *highly* dependent on knowing the floating point format, size of the integer, the endian-ness of the float and integer.  The following, or a variation, of it *may* work in OP's environment.

```
int floatExp_hack(float value) {
  if (isfinite(value)) {
    union {
      float f;
      value unsigned long ul;
    } u;
    assert(sizeof u.f == sizeof u.ul);
    u.f = value;
    return (u.ul >> 23) & 0xFF;
  }
  return tmax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a log in whatever base you're interested in getting an exponent in.

Hacking around with bits is only going to work if your platform uses IEEE floats, which isn't guaranteed. [Wikipedia's article on single precision IEEE floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) will show you what bits to mask, but note that some exponents have special values.